# Find k in k-means, but only between two options

Tags: clustering, k-means

There are many algorithms for finding $k$ in the $k$-means algorithm that depend on finding the "kink" in a graph of the objective function. What if I know that the data have either $2$ or $3$ clusters? How do I find which $k$ is "better"? Of course, a higher $k$ will lower the objective function, but this in not necessarily the "correct" k.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please mention what is the objective function which will be "of course lower for a higher k".

Comment: @ttnphns - I'm the usual euclidean metric, so the objective function is just the sum of distances squared.

Comment: To decide on the number of clusters it is always recommended to plot somehow normalized objective function (called an internal clustering criterion) in place of the function itself. Look for Calinski-Harabasz and Davies-Bouldin criterions, most appropriate for k-means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the usual measures for choosing between multiple values of K:

- Silhouette plot
- Davies-Bouldin
- BIC
- AIC

and probably there exist some more measures.